# HTML5 input type range for firefox orientation vertical?

Tags: css, html, firefox, input

Was wondering if anyone out there knows if vertical orientation on a `input` type range is possible in FireFox.

I know in Chrome and Safari you can do:

```
-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
```

And I tried something like this in FireFox:

**HTML**

```
<input type="range" name="range" min="0" max="9" step="1" value="3" />
```

**CSS**

```
input[name=range] {
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  -moz-transfrom: rotate(270deg);
}
```

Even though this does create the effect that I would like, the orientation of the range `input` default pointer still requires one to drag left and right for it to change, and not up and down as expected.

Here is an [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cn5fk/), must be viewed in FireFox.

Any new and exciting information on the subject would greatly be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a bug more than anything else. Consider filing a report on Bugzilla and see what they say.

Comment: adding `border:0;` style makes them prettier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like in the recent updates for Firefox, they have solved this problem. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cn5fk/251/)

```
<input type="range" name="range" min="0" max="9" step="1" value="3" />
```

And the CSS

```
input[name=range] {
    position:relative;
    top: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 0

    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
            transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having a look at the jqueryui slider implementation? 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#slider-vertical

Comment: This is my last resort, but very nice implementation. I like jQuery!

Comment: Quit throwing jQuery at every problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox supports the `orient="vertical"` attribute:

```
<input type="range" orient="vertical" min="0" max="9" step="1" value="3" />
```

But Chrome doesn't.

Answer (score -2):

Firefox doesn't support `<input type="range">`.  Your example is using [fryn's slider polyfill](https://github.com/fryn/html5slider), so you need to file a bug on fryn's github issue tracker.

Comment: Firefox *does* support `<input type="range">` so what is it it doesn't support?