# graph for Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where there is a slider and a graph is drawn according to the value. The slider has values from 1 to 5 and there are also 5 chart types. In Chrome everything is fine. However, Firefox can't handle it. I am attaching a piece of code and asking how to solve this? Thank you

```
<div class="slidecontainer" style="height: 0 !important;">
<input type="range" min="1" max="5" aria-orientation="vertical" value="#{IVB.iQ.q1}" class="slider"
id="myRange" onclick="asd()" onchange="#{IVB.yAL()}" ondurationchange="asd()"/>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                google.charts.load('current', {
                    'packages': ['corechart']
                });
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                function asd(){
                    document.getElementById("j_idt26:est").value = document.getElementById("myRange").value
                    updateData();
                }

                function drawChart() {
                    let data;
                    if(document.getElementById("myRange").value == 1){
                        data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                            [' ', 'Mv', 'Mz'],
                            [' ', 0, 0],
                            [' ', 2000, -1000]
                        ]);
                    }
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I use it on my Java web app.

Comment: I use java bean here: onchange="#{IVB.yAL()}"

Comment: Is it possible to create a [mcve] without Java bean so that it can be reproduced in a JSFiddle?

Comment: OK I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code: https://jsfiddle.net/qdxnre72/

Comment: Yes? Where, please?

Comment: I posted a link.

Comment: Because the chart doesn't show up?

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing } after function body`. You have more opening brackets than closing brackets.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g23vLctk/ here's the exact entry, but the scroll bar doesn't move in firefox

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: missing ) after condition` in Firefox and `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'` in Chrome. Syntax errors are usually a reason for unexpected behavior.

Comment: I'm blind, can you be more specific please?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/lmvEGe2

Comment: I tried to delete all the semicolons one by one, but the error remains.

Comment: The problem could be caused by the Java functions. Therefore I asked for [mcve] without Java

Comment: "document.getElementById("j_idt26:est").value = document.getElementById("myRange").value;" here was not ; but it is not solution

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] without syntax errors.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c3exgjhq/ Here

Comment: Your code works for me in Firefox and Chrome. You can see it in the screenshot I've linked in a previous comment.

Comment: you can move the slider?

Comment: No, I forgot what your question was. I get `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` when I try to move the slider.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3cmvpqhr/ without error, but still fail

Comment: Now you should edit your question, add this code and wait for someone else. I can't help here but I think I've already seen a very similar problem here on Stack Overflow. I can move the slider when I remove the CSS. It seems like Firefox doesn't support `-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;`. The slider actually works but with a width of `15px` you can't see the movement. Change the width to `150px` and you see it: https://jsfiddle.net/jdrokv9n/

Comment: Found a duplicate: [HTML5 input type range for firefox orientation vertical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419644/html5-input-type-range-for-firefox-orientation-vertical) `-webkit` is a browser specific prefix. Firefox and other browsers will ignore these rules. The prefix for Firefox is `-moz`

Comment: Thanks. Fail was use -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;

Comment: Final solution:
.slider {
  
    width: 150px;
    height: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top: -310px;
    left: 840px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #26C6DA;
    outline: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);

    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical; was wrong.

Final solution:

```
.slider {
    width: 150px;
    height: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top: -310px;
    left: 840px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #26C6DA;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}
```